# Do different versions of Deus Ex: Human Revolution differ visually or mechanically? How so?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, version-differences

Deus Ex: Human Revolution is available on Xbox 360, PS3, and Windows-based computers via Steam. How do these versions differ?

Obviously the 360 version has achievements, while the PS3 version has trophies—and Steam's suite of community participation tools are an obvious inclusion in the PC version. I'm referring more to differences in performance, graphical quality, user interface, or even in-game differences.

For example, in the PS2 port of the original Deus Ex, many areas had to be broken up into smaller chunks with large stone walls in order for it to fit into the PS2's memory. That's a pretty significant difference!

**Are the games functionally indistinguishable, and if not, what's the distinction?**

Comment: To some extent the answers to this may vary given the disparate hardware configurations of PC users - nonetheless, there are likely some key differences worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [that article](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2011/08/deus-ex-human-revolution-on-pc-hands-on-with-the-best-version-of-the-game.ars) on Ars Technica, the PC version has a few graphical enhancements:

- Use of DirectX 11-specific functionality.
- Support for AMD's HD3D and EyeInfinity technologies
- Higher resolution options (well, obviously)

The user interface is also reported to have been optimised for use with a keyboard, and mouse controls can be customised to fit your preferences.

I do not know whether the XBox 360 and PS3 versions differ in any significant way in either graphics or UI.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to jhominal, you can find a detailed comparison of the 360 and PS3 versions here:
[Lens Of Truth: Dues Ex: Human Revolution](http://www.lensoftruth.com/head2head-deus-ex-human-revolution-analysis/)